# tmux.conf: Prefix depends on whether session is remote

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to run tmux sessions inside and outside of a remote ssh session, so I want to use c-b prefix for the outer (local) session and c-a prefix inner (remote) session.

My question is how can it be done with a single tmux.conf. It's easy to check with bash if the session is remote using something like `[ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]`, but I don't know how to reliably incorporate this into tmux.conf, given that `if` appears to [be asynchronous and subject to race conditions](https://superuser.com/questions/539595/tmux-configuration-conditional-to-os).

Answer (score 3):

I made a workaround via .bash_profile:

```
if [[ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" && -n "$TMUX" ]] ; then
  tmux unbind c-b
  tmux set -g prefix c-a
  tmux bind c-a send-prefix
fi
```

It makes sure the `c-a` prefix is only set if the shell is running in a remote tmux window. Seems to work okay, but it would still be cleaner if it could be expressed in tmux.conf.